# Formula not identify cell values

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I'm generating an excel using the following code in my ASP.Net MVC Application

```
 var fileName =  DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd--hh-mm-ss") + ".xlsx";
                var outputDir = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ExcelUploadPath"];

                //  var fileName = "ExcellData.xlsx";
                var file = new FileInfo(outputDir + fileName);

                var fDate = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>(fromDate);
            var tDate = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>(toDate);
                using (var package = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage(file))
                {
                    // add a new worksheet to the empty workbook
                    ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Plan " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());

                    // --------- Data and styling goes here -------------- //

                    DataTable dt = planService.GetFlow(fDate, tDate, customerId, ordertypeId, suppliers, items);
                    if (dt != null)
                    {
                        int iCol = 1;
                        // Add column headings...
                        for (int i = 9; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                        {
                            dt.Columns[i].ColumnName = dt.Columns[i].ColumnName.MultiInsert("/", 1, 3);
                        }




                        foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
                        {
                            worksheet.Cells[1, iCol].Value = c.ColumnName;
                            worksheet.Cells[1, iCol].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                            worksheet.Cells[1, iCol].Style.Font.Bold = true;
                            worksheet.Cells[1, iCol].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.LightGray);
                            iCol++;
                        }




                        for (int j = 0; j < dt.Rows.Count; j++)
                        {
                            for (int k = 0; k < dt.Columns.Count; k++)
                            {

                                worksheet.Cells[j + 2, k + 1].Value = dt.Rows[j].ItemArray[k].ToString();



                                if (int.Parse(dt.Rows[j].ItemArray[7].ToString()) == 6)
                                {
                                    worksheet.Cells[j + 2, k + 1].Style.Locked = false;
                                    worksheet.Cells[j + 2, k + 1].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                                    worksheet.Cells[j + 2, k + 1].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Cyan);
                                }
                                if (int.Parse(dt.Rows[j].ItemArray[7].ToString()) == 7)
                                {
                                    worksheet.Cells[j + 2, k + 1].Style.Locked = false;
                                    worksheet.Cells[j + 2, k + 1].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                                    worksheet.Cells[j + 2, k + 1].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Magenta);
                                     //worksheet.Cells[j + 2, k + 1].Formula = 

                                    if((k+1) > 10){

                                        var addressList = new List<string>();
                                        for (int i = 11; i <= k+1; i++)
                                        {
                                            addressList.Add(worksheet.Cells[((j + 2) -1) , i].Address);
                                        }
                                        var lstAdress = String.Join(",", addressList);
                                        worksheet.Cells[j + 2, k + 1].Formula = "SUM(" + lstAdress + ")";
                                    }

                                }
                                if (int.Parse(dt.Rows[j].ItemArray[7].ToString()) == 8)
                                {
                                    //worksheet.Cells[j + 2, k + 1].Style.Locked = false;
                                    worksheet.Cells[j + 2, k + 1].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                                    worksheet.Cells[j + 2, k + 1].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.Gray);
                                }
                            }

                            var colCount = dt.Columns.Count;
                            // worksheet.Cells[j+2, 8, j+2, colCount- 1].Style.Numberformat.Format = "0.000";
                            var range = worksheet.Cells[j + 2, 9, j + 2, colCount - 1];
                            var r = range.ToString();
                            var decimalValidation = worksheet.DataValidations.AddDecimalValidation(range.ToString());
                            decimalValidation.ShowErrorMessage = true;
                            decimalValidation.ErrorStyle = ExcelDataValidationWarningStyle.stop;
                            decimalValidation.ErrorTitle = "The value you entered is not valid";
                            decimalValidation.Error = "This cell must be a valid positive number.";
                            decimalValidation.Operator = ExcelDataValidationOperator.greaterThanOrEqual;
                            decimalValidation.Formula.Value = 0D;

                        }


                        worksheet.Cells[worksheet.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();
                        worksheet.Column(1).Hidden = true;
                        worksheet.Column(2).Hidden = true;
                        worksheet.Column(3).Hidden = true;
                        worksheet.Column(4).Hidden = true;
                        worksheet.Column(5).Hidden = true;
                        worksheet.Column(8).Hidden = true;
                        worksheet.Column(9).Hidden = true;
                        worksheet.Column(10).Hidden = true;
                        worksheet.Protection.IsProtected = true;
                        // save our new workbook and we are done!


                        worksheet.Calculate();
                        package.Save();
                        return Json(fileName, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return Json("NoData", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                    }
                }
                return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Here I'm setting my formula with comma separated cell names eg:

> SUM(A1,A2,A3.. etc)

The excel file is generating correctly. But the problem is the formula calculation is not happen when I open my excel file.

[image]

The formula works when I manually change a cell value in Column Type **Agreed Flow**.

And it can only identify values of manually edited cells.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Formula recalculation is both an Excel and a workbook setting.

You could set it with at the workbook level with

```
workbook.CalcMode = ExcelCalcMode.Automatic;
```

If the *user* has set it to manual though, the formulas won't be recalculated.

If you want to ensure the saved values are correct you can force the calculation by calling

```
worksheet.Calculate();
```

You can also calculate the formulas at the workbook or range level, eg :

```
worksheet.Cells[j + 2, k + 1].Calculate();
```

or

```
package.Workbook.Calculate();
```

This is explained in [the documentation](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Formula-Calculation). Keep in mind that EPPlus doesn't contain Excel's formula engine. It uses its own engine to parse and calculate formulas. Some things aren't supported

Comment: The issue is formula is not calculating when open Excel document.
It only works when I change a cell value manually & it only recognize manually edited cell values

Comment: @tarzanbappa and that's what this answer explains. You *can't* control the user's settings. You can set CalcMode to Automatic but the end user can still override it. If you want to ensure the data is up to date, you have to calculate the formulas while saving.

Comment: @tarzanbappa what *are* the user's settings anyway? If the same user sees the same behaviour with workbooks created by Excel, there's nothing you can do in *code*

Comment: It worked when I change my formula to calculate the sum without using the SUM function

Comment: @tarzanbappa which doesn't explain anything. `SUM` isn't broken. Did you open the *saved* file or the *downloaded* file? Excel opens downloaded files in Read-Only mode for security reasons, as it should. BTW you *didn't* mention this is part of an ASP.NET application. It's not apparent until someone scrolls to the very end of the code dump

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I change my formula as follows..

```
    var addressList = new List<string>();
  for (int i = 11; i <= k+1; i++)
  {
      addressList.Add(worksheet.Cells[((j + 2) -1) , i].Address);
  }
  var lstAdress = String.Join("+", addressList);
   worksheet.Cells[j + 2, k + 1].Formula = "(" + lstAdress + ")";
```

I think there is an issue in my excel sheet when I use the **SUM** function So I write the formula without using it. Then it worked

> (A1+B1+C1+D1+ ..... etc)

Comment: No there is absolutely no issue with SUM at all. Literally *millions* of Excel users would have noticed 20 years ago. But *downloaded* files are read-only. You didn't mention this is an ASP.NET application, nor is it apparent until someone scrolls down to the end of the code dump. You didn't explain what the steps to reproduce the problem were either

Comment: no I didn't mean that there is a issue in the excel SUM function. I mean there is an issue in my excel sheet when I use SUM function.

Comment: If you want to solve this, post a *minimal* reproducible example. And mention all the important info. Excel will treat any downloaded file as a *read-only* file. Calculations won't work untile you enable editing. BTW you can use `sheet.LoadFromDataTable()` or `LoadFromCollection` to eliminate quite a lot of code.